# Android Studio cannot sync and build NEW and OLD kotlin projects

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle

When I am creating a new project in Android Studio, and load old projects I got this:

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/internal/impldep/com/google/common/collect/Lists**
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.internal.impldep.com.google.common.collect.Lists
**ERROR: Unable to load class 'org.gradle.internal.impldep.com.google.common.collect.Lists'.**
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt

Now I am totally stucked with that.

```
1,    I downloaded studio again and installed to an other drive, the probleme still exists.  
2,    I deleted all of my Android Studios from my computer, I downloaded and installed again. Started a new kotlin  project, the same error happened.  
3,    invalidate/restart not fixed 
4,    redownload dependencies not fixed
5,    update gradle not fixed
6,    flutter plugin disabled, not fixed
```

I was used my old Android Studio for flutter/dart and kotlin too. It looks like I can not build anymore native apps/kotlin.

my gradle wrapper

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "hu.lacas.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

**app build gradle**

Any way to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LOL. I found an old project what were built!!!
I copied this strings from that:**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71"
}
```

and

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

and finally synced, built!!!

**Something is very broken in the new Android Studio, because I got a lot of error/sync failed even if I create a NEW PROJECT**